# Квадратные ячейки в таблице QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt4

В QtableWidget нужно сделать так чтоб все ячейки были квадратными и не изменялись .Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такая конструкция делает ячейки 30*30 с запретом изменения размера.

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setCascadingSectionResizes(false);
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setCascadingSectionResizes(false);

ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setMinimumSectionSize(30);
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setMaximumSectionSize(30);
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(30);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setMinimumSectionSize(30);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setMaximumSectionSize(30);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(30);

QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
```